# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iloc' while splitting dataset into X and y variables

Tags: python

I'm getting an error while splitting the data into X and y dataset

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

train.head(5)

train.columns[train.isnull().any()]

train=train.drop('Id',axis=1)
test=test.drop('Id',axis=1)

train['LotFrontage']=train['LotFrontage'].fillna(0)
train['MasVnrArea']=train['MasVnrArea'].fillna(0)
train['GarageYrBlt']=train['GarageYrBlt'].fillna(0)

cat_cols = ['MSZoning','Alley','Street','LotShape','LandContour','Utilities','LotConfig','LandSlope','Neighborhood','Condition1','Condition2','BldgType','HouseStyle','RoofStyle','RoofMatl','Exterior1st','Exterior2nd','MasVnrType','ExterQual','ExterCond','Foundation','BsmtQual','BsmtCond','BsmtExposure','BsmtFinType1','BsmtFinType2','Heating','HeatingQC','CentralAir','Electrical','KitchenQual','Functional','FireplaceQu','GarageType','GarageFinish','GarageQual','GarageCond','PavedDrive','PoolQC','Fence','MiscFeature','SaleType','SaleCondition']

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

for col in cat_cols:
    if col in train.columns:
        le=LabelEncoder()
        i = train.columns.get_loc(col)
        train[col] =le.fit_transform(list(train[col].values))

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder()
train = onehotencoder.fit_transform(train).toarray()

X_train = train.iloc[:,:-1].values
```

the error is :

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Comment: train = onehotencoder.fit_transform(train).toarray() - seems you need to delete toarray

Answer (score 0):

```
train = onehotencoder.fit_transform(train).toarray()
```

train is now a `numpy` array. `iloc` is only used to index `pandas` dataframes.